# brightness of the screen according to area

Tags: 20.04, brightness

I have a serious problem with my eyes. I want to adjust the brightness level of the screen according to the area of the screen. For instance, I would like to only brighten two or three lines when I read a pdf file. Other areas should be very dark and when clicked temporarily brightened.Is there such a utility?

Comment: I think there is a "Docked Screen Magnifier" in the accessibility options. You know, the little guy at the top right corner of the login screen. There is also an accessibility tab in the System Settings. See https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/a11y-mag.html.en#:~:text=You%20can%20quickly%20turn%20zoom,of%20the%20Zoom%20Options%20window. for more help